# Converting folder and file structure into a nested dict with files listed

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to convert a directory structure into a json file.

So, first I need to get all the folders {keys} and files [list] into a nested dict. I can get the nested folders as below, but how do I include the list of files?

```
def fs_tree(root):
    results = {}
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dir_path):
        print(filenames)
        parts = dirpath.split(os.sep)

        idx = parts.index(root_dir)
        parts = parts[idx + 0:]

        curr = results
        for p in parts:
            curr = curr.setdefault(p, {})
    return results

tree = fs_tree(dir_path)
```

The above results in:

```
{'level_0': 
    {
        'level_1a': {}, 
        'level_1b': {}, 
        'level_1c': {}, 
        'level_1d': {}, 
        'level_1e': {
                        'level_2a': {}
                    }, 
        'level_1f': {}
    }
}
```

But I would like it so that the files are listed in each dict, something like this:

```
{'level_0': [files]
    {
        'level_1a': {[files]}, 
        'level_1b': {[files]}, 
        'level_1c': {[files]}, 
        'level_1d': {[files]}, 
        'level_1e': [files]
            {
                'level_2a': {[files]}
            }, 
        'level_1f': {[files]}
    }
}
```

Once done I can use json.dump() to export the dict to a json file.

Comment: maybe I missed something but your expected json looks invalid - can you give example with real values instead of `[files]`

Comment: you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400599/store-directory-structure-in-nested-dictionary-in-python